# c++ What is wrong with my script?

Tags: c++

Basically I want to square any number I input. Why does this not work?

I compiles but it does not square my input.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float SquareNumber;
float Squared = SquareNumber * SquareNumber;



int main()
{

    cout << "Please enter a number to be squared: ";
    cin >> SquareNumber;

    cout << SquareNumber << " squared is " << Squared;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: You are not doing any operations on the input, try that to begin with: `SquareNumber = SquareNumber * SquareNumber;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you tell us a bit more about what you've tried so far? What inputs are you running it on and what outputs are you seeing? What have you done so far to try to figure out what the error is? Do you have any guesses, and if so, why?

Comment: @Aidin sure there is an operation, it just happens during static initalization.

Comment: You need to go and do a tutorial or buy a book. You're fairly wide of the mark...

Comment: @Flexo Yeah, missed it since it was in such a hidden totally unexpected place.

Comment: You are obviously new. You can ask for help here, but you can also learn by posting to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Do that when your code is working, to ask how you can improve it and you will learn how to code better

Comment: @Mawg Nope! That's not appropriate for SE Code Review,

Comment: Inside the main method you need to calculate the value then, from the value filled in. You have done it in the wrong place.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  0 no offence, but why? Does it not help our new member? It is just a comment - I also post an answer, which I hope is acceptable. Just curious, as to how I can be a better SE member :-)

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 4):

> I compiles but it does not square my input.

You need to compute the square after you input the number. At the time `Squared` is computed, the value of `SquaredNumber` is 0.0. Hence, the value of `Squared` is also 0.0.

The line

```
float Squared = SquareNumber * SquareNumber;
```

sets the value of `Squared` using the value of `SquaredNumber` at that time. It **does not update** the value of `Square` when the value of `SquaredNumber` is changed. To get that effect, you need to use a function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float SquareNumber;

float Squared(float in)
{
   return in * in;
}

int main()
{
   cout << "Please enter a number to be squared: ";
   cin >> SquareNumber;

   cout << SquareNumber << " squared is " << Squared(SquareNumber);

   return 0;
};
```

Comment: Why do you need the function vs. the statement?

Comment: I always prefer functions to simple statements. A function captures the abstraction while a statement simply captures the implementation details of that abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not correctly calculating the square. You do it as "[compile time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time)", rather than at "[run time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_time)".

Just change your code to this, but be sure that you understand why  - and ask here if you do not (hint: how can you calculate the square of a number, before you know what the number is?).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    float SquareNumber;
    float Squared;

    cout << "Please enter a number to be squared: ";
    cin >> SquareNumber;

   Squared = SquareNumber * SquareNumber;   // calculate at *run time*

   cout << SquareNumber << " squared is " << Squared;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
};
```